# Log in with a specific username with Google API

Tags: api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I am developing a web app for a group, and I want to be able to let anyone in the group create an event and add it to the group's calendar through the app. I was able to get the basic functionality working using Google Calendar API v3 for Javascript -- you could fill out a form with the event's start/end times, title, information, etc, and it could insert that event into the calendar.

But the problem is with authentication. If a user is logged in to a Google account that is not given permission to create events on the calendar, they are unable to add the event (Javascript writes "Forbidden" to the console). If I log out of all Google accounts and then sign in with the account that owns the calendar, the event is created with no problems (that makes sense).

Adding every single person in the group to the edit-permissions on the calendar seems like too much of a "brute force" method.

Is there a way to always authenticate the Google account that owns the calendar? Or, better yet, is there a way just to force authentication in general, even if someone is already logged in to Google / authorized to the app? Some people in the group know the calendar login/password, so if I could always bring up a Google login screen, they could just enter the calendar account information and then add the event from there. Again, I'm using Javascript (not much documentation on this...).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Service Accounts. That way the calendar is owned by the application, and so the application will always have permission to update it.

Comment: I came back to this project a year later, and significant improvements had been made to the API. I was able to get the code working! Thanks for the suggestion for service accounts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid authentication problem from other opened session in user browser, you have to authenticate on the calendar, using server side library.

check this link:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth

it bounces you from one article to other, but at the end you should get all information.